# Generating an MDM APNS certificate in wso2 emm

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

Do we have to generate an MDM APNS certificate to be able to register in wso2 emm console with iphones and ipads? Is this step neccessary or just an extra option?

Also, how long will it take wso2 to give me a signed csr file in .plist format? Are there any charges is  this service free?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any solution?

Actually after fill all details of form on http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/csr/ URL. It will not send any further detail to mail.

How can I receive plist file from WSO server?

please give suggest if any...

=============

## EDIT 1

After 24-26 hours received both files 'plist_encoded' and 'WSO2 MDM Connector for iOS.zip'

Please close question with answer to right mark.

Comment: When did you fill the details?

Comment: yesterday evening only. Is it take time to receive response from WSO? Or is there any paid service?

Comment: Did you receive this?

Comment: @Dilshan, I have received email from WSO with 'plist_encoded' and 'WSO2 MDM Connector for iOS.zip' two files after 24-30 hours from request.